# Your current session has been expired. Magento2

Tags: php, magento, session, magento2

I just migrate my site to localhost and everything working fine. but when i try to logged into  my admin pannel then its through me error like **`Your current session has been expired.`**

I removed all the cache from the folder also change the setting from database about session expiration time.

also we have tried each and every possible solution from [this](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5309) thread.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16):

This is the perfect solution

first step:
find "admin/security/session_lifetime" in table core_config_data.
if not exist create one and set value to 86400

second step:
clean cache (remove var/cache)

login and fix

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5309

Comment: Forget about table manipulation and use the CLI `php bin/magento config:set admin/security/session_lifetime 86400 && php bin/magento cache:flush`

Comment: That entry does not even exist in my table... why??

Answer (score 6):

I was facing same issue, After some research I had found the solution for admin login issue.

It's occured due to MySql TIMESTAMP and MySql version issue.

If we are using MySql 5.5.x than we need to take care about TIMESTAMP.

Here is the perfect solution which helps you to overcome the admin login issue of session.

**Go to : `admin_user_session` table in MySql
Set `created_at` column to '0' and `updated_at` column to 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' as it is.**

Refresh admin page and try to login again, it will work **100%**

Thanks.

Comment: The column "created_at" can't be setted to '0'

Comment: Which MySql version are you using? Have you tried with null values?

Comment: I have successfully setted the column to '0'... But I doesn't work :(   I got the message : "Your current session has been expired."

Comment: I am trucate table admin_user_session on my dev site and its works

Answer (score 1):

You need just to modify a value in your table [core_config_data] in database.

1. Open PHPMYADMIN
2. run:
   UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = 864000 WHERE `path` = 'admin/security/session_lifetime'
3. login into admin pannel again

I hope this could help you.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the times on all your servers are in sync.  You do not need to update any tables.

Comment: @TeroLahtinen DB server always runs time and here the admin login is not working but the frontend order facility works correctly and orders stores the time when the order is creating.

Answer (score 1):

**Admin Side login that time session expired**

[session expired Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dk8fW.jpg)

1 step: Find "admin/security/session_lifetime" in table core_config_data.

**if not exist create one and set value to 86400**

second step:
clean cache (remove var/cache)

login and fix

Answer (score -5):

Run the below commonds in your local server.

First, clean cache and index all

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Still have issue then deploy again:

rm -rf pub/static/* // remove all static folder content

rm -rf var/* // remove var folder content

bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

chmod -R 7777 var pub/static // set permission (not need in local server)

Comment: Destroyed my theme and did not helped at all.

Comment: Do not delete all content in var!